# Using ValidatesRequests trait in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here's the code from my `AuthController`:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:5|max:15',
    ]);
}
```

If the validation fails I'm getting redirected to the previous page. Is there a way to pass additional data along with the input and the errors (which are handled by the trait)?

**Edit**: Actually, the trait does exactly what I want, except the additional data I want to pass. As @CDF suggested in the answers I should modify the `buildFailedValidationResponse` method which is `protected`.

Should I create a new custom trait, which will have the same functionality as the `ValidatesRequests` trait (that comes with Laravel) and edit the `buildFailedValidationResponse` method to accept one more argument **or** traits can be easily modified following another approach (if any exists)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, check the example in the documentation:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches[1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches)

Using the fails(); method, you can flash the errors and inputs values in the session and get them back with after redirect. To pass other datas just flash them with the with(); method.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
return back()->withErrors($validator)
->withInput()
->with($foo);
    }
```